# Pandas add total row at the end of each unique column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, that looks something like :

```
Item    Type  Location    Count
1       Dog   USA         10
2       Dog   UK          20
3       Cat   JAPAN       30
4       Cat   UK          40
5       Bird  CHINA       50
6       Bird  SPAIN       60
7       Bird  UAE         70
```

I would like to add "Total" row of the sum "Count" column to the end of each unique "Type" column, Morover : I would like to fill down the "Type" column only, as below :

```
Item    Type  Location    Count
1       Dog   USA         10
2       Dog   UK          20
Total   Dog               30
3       Cat   JAPAN       30
4       Cat   UK          40
Total   Cat               70
5       Bird  CHINA       50
6       Bird  SPAIN       60
7       Bird  UAE         70
Total   Bird              180
```

What i have tried, which it sums all the "Count" row values :

```
df.loc["Count"] = df.sum()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First reset the index of the dataframe then group the dataframe on `Type` and aggregate the column `Count` using `sum` and `index` using `max`, then assign the `Item` column whose value is `Total`. Finally [`.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the `frame` with the original dataframe `df` and [`.sort`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) the index to maintain the order.

```
frame = df.reset_index()\
          .groupby('Type', as_index=False)\
          .agg({'Count': 'sum', 'index': 'max'})\
          .assign(Item='Total').set_index('index')

pd.concat([df, frame]).sort_index(ignore_index=True)
```

Another approach you might want to try (might be faster than the above one):

```
def summarize():
    for k, g in df.groupby('Type', sort=False):
        yield g.append({'Item': 'Total',
                        'Type': k, 'Location': '',
                        'Count': g['Count'].sum()}, ignore_index=True)


pd.concat(summarize(), ignore_index=True)
```

which results:

```
    Item  Type Location  Count
0      1   Dog      USA     10
1      2   Dog       UK     20
2  Total   Dog              30
3      3   Cat    JAPAN     30
4      4   Cat       UK     40
5  Total   Cat              70
6      5  Bird    CHINA     50
7      6  Bird    SPAIN     60
8      7  Bird      UAE     70
9  Total  Bird             180
```

Comment: my favorite one  so far

Comment: hey @anky Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby("Type").agg({"Count": "sum"})
```